# Getting error "The data couldn’t be read because it is missing." during fetching data using alamofire and swift

Tags: swift, alamofire, codable

I am fetching data from server in swift using Alamofire and codable. But i am getting error

> The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.

is there anything wrong in my code? why i am getting error like this?

My code:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Welcome
struct UserDetails: Codable {
let success: Int
let message: String
let result: UserResult

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case success = "Success"
    case message = "Message"
    case result = "Result"
}
}

// MARK: - Result
struct UserResult: Codable {
let userID: Int
let firstName, location, state, about: String
let totalScore: Int
let sun, rising, moon: String
let ego, communication, birthStar, sexual: Int
let intellectual, temperament, emotional, healthGenetic: Int
let profilePic: String
let numberOfPhotos: Int
let imagelist: [Imagelist]
let verified: Int
let dateOfBirth, timeOfBirth: String
let age: Int

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case userID = "User_Id"
    case firstName = "First_Name"
    case location = "Location"
    case state = "State"
    case about = "About"
    case totalScore = "TotalScore"
    case sun
    case rising = "Rising"
    case moon = "Moon"
    case ego = "Ego"
    case communication = "Communication"
    case birthStar = "Birth_star"
    case sexual = "Sexual"
    case intellectual = "Intellectual"
    case temperament = "Temperament"
    case emotional = "Emotional"
    case healthGenetic = "Health_Genetic"
    case profilePic = "Profile_Pic"
    case numberOfPhotos = "NumberOfPhotos"
    case imagelist, verified
    case dateOfBirth = "DateOfBirth"
    case timeOfBirth = "TimeOfBirth"
    case age = "Age"
}
}

// MARK: - Imagelist
struct Imagelist: Codable {
let userID: Int
let imagePath: String

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case userID = "User_Id"
    case imagePath = "Image_path"
}
}


import Foundation
import Alamofire

class ApiRequest {

func getUserDetailData(_ userId: Int, _ accessToken: String, completion: @escaping UserProfileDetailsData) {

    guard let url = URL(string: "\(USER_PROFILE_URL)?UserID=\(userId)&RequestingUser_id=1")  else{return}
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.get.rawValue

    urlRequest.addValue(accessToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    Alamofire.request(urlRequest).responseJSON { (response) in
        if let error = response.result.error {
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(nil)
            return
        }

        guard let data = response.data else { return completion(nil)}
        let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let person = try jsonDecoder.decode(UserDetails.self, from: data)

            completion(person)
        } catch {
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(nil)
        }
    }

}
}
```

In my constant class i have following two codes

```
let USER_PROFILE_URL = URL_BASE + "GetUserProfile/"

typealias UserProfileDetailsData = (UserDetails?) -> Void
```

I am calling the api in my view controller like:

```
 func getUserDetailsData(_ userId: Int, accessToken: String) {
    apiRequest.getUserDetailData(userId, accessToken) { (userDetails) in

        self.userDataResult = userDetails?.result


    }
}
```

I am getting data from server like

```
{
"Success": 1,
"Message": "Record Get Successfully.",
"Result": {
    "User_Id": 230,
    "First_Name": "Fgfdg",
    "Location": "Fond du Lac County",
    "State": " Wisconsin",
    "About": "SDFDdsgsGgsddsSSGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG",
    "TotalScore": 27,
    "sun": "Scorpio",
    "Rising": "Scorpio",
    "Moon": "Libra",
    "Ego": 100,
    "Communication": 100,
    "Birth_star": 99,
    "Sexual": 50,
    "Intellectual": 100,
    "Temperament": 99,
    "Emotional": 0,
    "Health_Genetic": 100,
    "Profile_Pic": "Images/ProfilePic/yugva0y.jpg",
    "NumberOfPhotos": 8,
    "imagelist": [
        {
            "User_Id": 230,
            "Image_path": "Images/UploadImage/uUk8lUP.jpg"
        },
        {
            "User_Id": 230,
            "Image_path": "Images/UploadImage/Sf5jBIU.jpg"
        },
        {
            "User_Id": 230,
            "Image_path": "Images/UploadImage/uw8hdNt.jpg"
        },
        {
            "User_Id": 230,
            "Image_path": "Images/UploadImage/vRdKGmM.jpg"
        },
        {
            "User_Id": 230,
            "Image_path": "Images/UploadImage/vQchUIO.jpg"
        },
        {
            "User_Id": 230,
            "Image_path": "Images/UploadImage/HYHQHiL.jpg"
        },
        {
            "User_Id": 230,
            "Image_path": "Images/UploadImage/owM3Al9.jpg"
        },
        {
            "User_Id": 230,
            "Image_path": "Images/UploadImage/T4ufyc6.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "verified": 0,
    "DateOfBirth": "1978-11-28",
    "TimeOfBirth": "07:52:00.0000000",
    "Age": 41
}
}
```

The error i am getting is:

> Swift.DecodingError.valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "Result", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "sun", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: For starters, print `error` instead of `error.localisedDescription` for a more detailed error message and have you debugged this or otherwise knows where the error occurs?

Comment: Where exactly do you get that error?

Comment: i am getting error: -      Swift.DecodingError.valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "Result", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "sun", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Please add that info in your question, it's very difficult to read in a comment. Also indicate on what line in your code you get the error.

Comment: yes i have added this to my question

Comment: Hi @koen. Actually there are lots of users, for some users, the of "sun", "Rising" and "Moon" values are nil . So after making these values optional(let sun, rising, moon: String?), the issue if resolved. Thanks for your time.

Comment: There should be something you missed while creating Datamodel of Json response, Check the naming of Datamodel and the same name is present in json decoding. 

You can copy the json response to website https://app.quicktype.io/  and replace your datamodel with qicktype.io . This should definately resolve the issue.